# Searching a word in the NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am getting a request data and putting it in NSString. after that, I am getting the following string,

> _*VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE1MjI5NTA5MzBkZBfGgdOVhk6K8WsSgq64ngCpAncw&*_EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBgKdhbkbAvOQn7cGApKGyNkMAsKL2t4DApSbgLYHArS6otoP2nSQkmm0E6zJe2u91W5ntimqJ18%3D&x-rim-queue-id=MyOfflineQueue&form_id=723&txt2=siddhesh.b.chavan%40gmail.com&btnSubmit=Submit&x-rim1-request1-title=SignatureShouldBeDoneHere&x-rim-request-title=iPhone3+4%2F6%2F2011+3%3A57%3A21+AM

The thing I have to ask is, I want to get the "form_id" from this string which is "723".
so, How do I get that??
I want to get the form_ID for a request everytime. So, kindly help me out of this.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you would like to try this: Let me know if it works.

```
NSInteger formId;
//separate the whole string first by "&" characters
NSArray *array = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
for (NSString *queryString in array)
{
    //for every separated string, look if you have the "form_id" key
    NSRange range = [queryString rangeOfString:@"form_id=" options:NSLiteralSearch];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
       NSLog(@"form_id query string does exist");
       //form_id= has 7 characters, pick the character which comes after the "=" sign.
       NSString *value = [queryString substringFromIndex:8];
       formId = [value integerValue];
    }
}
```

That solution is assuming that you only have 1 "form_id".

Answer (score 2):

These options are more intended for URL arguments parsing, which you are trying to do.

### 1. Range search : for a word, a character

#### *most efficient but can be fastidious to write... (and read!)*

See [`rangeOfString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a) and its friends on NSString documentation

### 2. Split

#### *quick and elegant to write, but not so efficient*

Since it is a URL argument style string, it is easily parsable by splitting on `&` and `=` witch can be done easily using [`componentsSeparatedByString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) or `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`

### 3. Regular expressions

#### *clean code, powerful*

Regular expressions are imho the best choice to manipulate text, but they can be harder to use/learn than previous solutions. To use regular expressions I suggest two options:

1. iPhone OS >= 3.2 has regular expressions :

   [`NSString rangeOfString:options:NSRegularExpressionSearch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3aoptions%3a)

   But this is close to option 1.
2. [RegexKitLit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/), with provides an excellent regular expression engine on OSX/iOS would provide, imho, the best and most powerful solution to your problem (and many others!!!)...

### 4. Other Kits/API/SDK

#### *the missing api/toolkit/sdk? don't write code thousands people already wrote...*

1. I wished that `NSURL` would support URL arguments, for parsing and build urls... but it does not.
2. I don't know a good URL parsing/toolbox library that offers such URL Arguments manipulation tools (Google Toolbox does not provide such URL arguments tools [except for escaping](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString+URLArguments.h) which is already really useful) but I'm sure that exists! And a good library, with tested and reliable code would be for sure your best solution...

### 5. Others... there are many

I forgot to mention `NSScanner` which I never really looked into (bad me)
More generally, [Apple documentation on this topic](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI) is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[myString substringToIndex:index];
[myString substringFromIndex:index];
[myString substringWithRange:range];
```

Or

```
if ( [yourString rangeOfString:@"form_id"].location == NSNotFound )
{
NSLog(@"form_id not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'rangeOfString:options:range:' start by searching the entire string for "form_id=" and then search from where that was found to for an "&". You will need to handle the case where the ampersand isnt found (when form_id is the last in the list).

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSScanner object too. Like-

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:reqData];  
[scanner scanUpToString:@"form_id" intoString:nil];  
[scanner scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:&strObj];  
valueStr = [strObj substringFromIndex:1];
```